# UITextField resignFirstResponder not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I've double checked all the connections in the nib file. My code -

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone_bg_login.png"]];
    self.title = @"Login screen";
    loginTxt = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    pwdText = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    loginFailedTxt = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    loginBtn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    navAppDelegate = (NavAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    navAppDelegate.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    //NSArray *subVs = (NSArray *) [self.view subviews];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I've used a subclass of `UIView (UIControl)` and added all the UI elements to it in the Interface builder.The `UIControl's touchDown` method is connected to `backgroundTap` method.

```
-(IBAction) backgroundTap:(id) sender {
    [loginTxt resignFirstResponder];
    [pwdText resignFirstResponder];
    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] becomeFirstResponder];
        //[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

So the keyboard isn't removed like it's supposed to. Not sure why.

Thanks for the help!
Teja.

Comment: Besides the memory-related issues in viewDidLoad, if loginTxt and pwdText are connected to controls in the nib, why are you doing alloc+init on them in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Damn, I didn't have these calls initially, but it probably wasn't working because I had the connections set up wrong. I wanted to test it out and see if this was the problem, so I put them in and just forgot to remove them after I recreated a new nib file. Thanks, this was the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DyingCactus has pointed to your error. You're replacing the NIB-version of the control with a completely different control, losing your pointer to the one in the NIB. When you call `resignFirstResponder`, you're calling it on your duplicate object, not the one that's actually on the screen. Get rid of the `alloc` and `init` calls for things wired in the NIB.